# Excel 2013 Forumla Not Working in some Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

SO I'm trying to get some work done in Excel 2013, and after getting an initial formula to work, I dragged it across several other cells. I did all the standard locking of references and such, even copied the exact formula into the new cell formula window with copy paste. The formula works in the first cell, not in those it's dragged over. It also works in seemingly random cells when pasted around (see screen shot).

Formula is below... this was a brand new sheet, the cells had not been initialized until the formula was pasted. Is this an issue with Excel 2013? Since the formula works in some pastes perfectly, and not in others, I don't think that's the issue... I changed the cell format after the pastes in a couple cells to see if that changed results at all - it does not.

Update: I added in the false value, and the IF is evaluating to false on the zero cells... why it's correctly true in some, and false in others is still a mystery.

```
=MIN(IF('Metrics'!$DL$2:$DL$1725=$L$2&$O$2,'Metrics'!$DH$2:$DH$1725))
```

[image]

Comment: Did you click on the formula to see if it is pointing to the cells you need ?

Comment: Yes, the formula is the exact same in all cells, in the formula window and the little colored cell highlights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that for the formula to correctly evaluate it should be set as an array (ctrl-shift-enter).
*However*, Excel 2013 seems to randomly recognize the formula as an array formula, and sometimes not. Thus the formula occasionally will work, in a brand new, uninitialized cell, using/displaying the standard formula, and a correct result. Other times it will still display the same formula, but produce incorrect results since it is not being evaluated as an array.

Any of the cells that did not magically convert to an array formula, when changed to array, will update with correct values.

Only manually changed cells reflect the `{=MIN(IF(...)...))}` indication of an array formula. Cells in which the formula produced correct results still display as a non-array formula.

Comment: Good one +1 , glad you shared the solution =) in 2003, 2010 it would have been easier to narrow down to the issue I reckon.

Comment: I don't think it's a question of Excel randomly recognising the formula as an array or not. If you enter this type of formula without "array entry" then the **position** of the formula will have an effect, e.g. if you enter the formula in a row where the IF condition is satisfied you will typically get the correct result - if you enter in another row you won't.

Comment: How does the cell entry location matter? The formula has a clearly delimited range that it should check - there is no relative positioning in the formula.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. I am having the exact same issue where the formula will work only on the first cell or if I type in values but when I copy down it does not work. I'm not sure what (ctrl-shift-enter) does or where to use it.

Comment: ctrl-shift-enter marks the selected region as an array (noted by the curly braces {} ). See here for Excel array resources: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar if not exactly the same issue. Try hitting F9 to recalc the sheet, or go to File>Options, go to "Formulas" and under "Workbook Calculations" set it to "Automatic".

Solved my problem, which manifested the same way yours did.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are,using `$` sign to *lock* the cells in the formula, it looks like you are just pointing it to the same cells giving you same results... Click on the formula and check or change to the correct reference cells as you desire...

Comment: It's locked on a range of cells...unlocking has no effect on the behavior of the sheet in response to the formula being pasted in different cells.

Answer (score 0):

turns out my 2003 excel problem was due to some circular formulas.  Had "Circular:" at the very bottom line. When these all fixed, the other cells started to calculate properly.