# Excel formula not working when dragging, but working when copying

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a formula that worked for my spreadsheet. However, after dragging it across several other cells, it didn't work anymore. Then I pasted the same formula to the next cells and suddenly I did get the correct answer. I am copying the two formulas (dragged and copied) below to show that they are identical.

**Dragged Formula**

```
=IF(AND($B$37=K7,K20>0),SLN(K20,0,'Assumptions and Return'!$J$106),IF(AND(K7>$B$37,J37>0,SUM($E$37:K37)<'Assumptions and Return'!$J$97),J37,0))
```

**Copied Formula**

```
=IF(AND($B$37=K7,K20>0),SLN(K20,0,'Assumptions and Return'!$J$106),IF(AND(K7>$B$37,J37>0,SUM($E$37:K37)<'Assumptions and Return'!$J$97),J37,0))
```

I need to figure out how to make the formula work while dragging it. I found a previous post ([[Excel 2013 Forumla Not Working in some Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444416/excel-2013-forumla-not-working-in-some-cells])), which is related to this issue.
However, the answer did not help. Neither has it anything to do with Calculation Options. 
My Excel Sheet is set to "Automatic calculations".

Does anyone have experience with this issue? Did you find a solution? Would you be willing to share it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you **drag** a cell, it is the same as *cutting* and *pasting* a cell, so there is no way to achieve what you're trying to do.  The only other option you have for *copying* a formula is hovering over the bottom right corner until your cursor becomes a cross and dragging the formula either horizontally or vertically to copy across all the cells.

Comment: Hi Michael, first of all thank you for your reply. I am not sure if I understand why I can't achieve this. In order to try answer your comment, I would like to explain how I tried to copy the formula to the other cells. So, I copied the cell F37 using Ctrl+C and pasted it to the rest of the row using Ctrl+R (fill right). It gave me the expected result in J37, but not in any of the following cells (K37, L37, M37, etc.) However, when I copy/pasted J37 to K37, I suddenly did get the correct result. This is what surprises me, because the formula is exactly the same with the 2 methods.

Comment: Have you used the Trace Precedents button on the ribbon to comparethe last working cell with the first non-working cell? Also try the evaluate function to step through the formula to see why it returns a different result. I am thinking one of the cell addresses may be off somehow. Another possible gotcha would be if there were hidden columns that you drug across. Things to try.